# Using react routes for routing in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to setup the routes for a simple react application and react-router doesn't seem to match the given routes in the switch defaults the 404 page

Here is the code for the routes:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

window.React = React;

render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <HashRouter>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />

        <Route path="list-days" component={App} />

        <Route path="add-day" component={AddDayForm} />
        <Route component={Whoops404} />
      </HashRouter>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And here is the code for the links to those routes:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { IoIosHome as Home } from "react-icons/io";
import { FaCalendarPlus } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FaTable } from "react-icons/fa";

export const Menu = () => (
  <nav className="Menu">
    <Link to="/" activeclassname="selected">
      <Home />
    </Link>
    <Link to="/add-day" activeclassname="selected">
      <FaCalendarPlus />
    </Link>
    <Link to="/list-days" activeclassname="selected">
      <FaTable />
    </Link>
  </nav>
```

When you click anything but the home link the 404 page is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You use 'links' as HTML structure and have this not inherited in import from "react-router-dom";
Per seeing the documentation of react this all is provided with this import statement.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, may you kindly elaborate

Comment: You forgot the 'Link' in import, since you use link as HTML <Link to="/" />

Comment: I imported the Link where I used in the Menu component, sorry I didn't include the import statements in the menu component.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `/` to your Routes' path.

`<Route path="/list-days" component={App} />`

Comment: This seems to work but still matches 404 component as well, both components are shown

Comment: Your `Switch` must wrap the `Route` components. Move `HashRouter` up.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you use both `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have defined your Route like

```
<Route path="list-days" component={App} />
```

and you are accessing those links as

```
<Link to="/list-days" activeclassname="selected"></Link>
```

You can see the difference that your are adding a front slash when accessing through Link. Just put a front slash on Route like this:

```
<Route path="/list-days" component={App} />
```

will solve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to work but still matches 404 component as well, both components are shown, how do I deal with this?

Comment: use exact key
<Route path="/list-days" exact component={App} />

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are using [hash router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter).

try this:

```
return (
    <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="#/" component={App} />

          <Route path="#/list-days" component={App} />

          <Route path="#/add-day" component={AddDayForm} />
          <Route component={Whoops404} />
        <Switch>
    </HashRouter>
)
```

or why not just switch to [browserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) so you wouldn't need those hashes on your url?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove HashRouter and edit your route to be like this

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route exact path="/list-days" component={App} />
    <Route exact path="/add-day" component={AddDayForm} />
    <Route exact path="*" component={Whoops404} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```